# Need to change the JMS_IBM_Character_Set Property value while sending request to IBMMQ with Apache Camel and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, ibm-mq, mq

**Use-Case:** I'm sending a request to IBM MQ Listener from Spring Boot App with Apache camel, while sending I have to change the MQ JMS Property JMS_IBM_Character_Set=UTF-8 but these changes are not reflecting at Listener side

Could anyone please help me how to change the property value for IBM MQ with Apache Camel

**// Request Queue - one direction**

```
@Component
public class RequestRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:request").
        setProperty("JMS_IBM_Character_Set", constant("true")).
        to("jms:REQUEST.Q1?disableReplyTo=true")
        .log("Received Body is  ${body}   and header info is   ${headers}  "); 
    }
}
```

**//  Below one Request-Reply Queue**

```
@Component
public class RequestReplyRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:request-reply").setProperty("JMS_IBM_Character_Set", constant("true"))
                .to("log:like-to-see-all?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true")
                .to("jms:REQUEST.Q1?ReplyTo=REPLY.Q1&exchangePattern=InOut")
                .log("Request-reply Body is  ${body}   and header info is   ${headers}  ");

        from("jms:REPLY.Q1")
                .log("Received Body is  ${body}   and header info is   ${headers}  ");
    }

}
```

Comment: You want 37 not UTF-8 right?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you know it is not reflected at the Listener side?

Comment: i wanna use UTF-8

Comment: MyApp (Produce Q1) ---------------- >OtherApp(Q1 -Listener) 
MyApp(Q2 Listener)<------------ Other App(Q2 -Produce) 


I'm setting these headers in MyApp Q1, Other App placing header from Q1 to Q2 and forwarding to the Q2
Listener, in MyApp Q2 Listener i'm not getting expected headers.

Comment: In your other question you showed working code using 37.

Comment: 37 is working with spring jms not apache camel

Comment: JMS default is UTF-8, I think you want camel also to send in 37,  I explained this in your first question.

Comment: Yes UTF-8 is the default one, but in my case, it's values changes to IBM037 at IBM MQ listeners side, how can I make the default value

Comment: is the producer jms or is the consumer?

Answer (score 1):

When I put a message on IBM MQ with JMS client in 2017 i could not make it. I changed jms client to IBMMQ.jar in order to put a message with header. I suggest you that you can read JMS document on Apache camel site. Also, try to use "allowAdditionalHeaders"

Comment: thanks for the reply I'm not getting proper examples, how to use the "allowAdditionalHeaders" property, if I use like below I'm not getting any error but my header value is not reflecting at IBM MQ listeners side.     to("jms:REQUEST.Q1?disableReplyTo=true&allowAdditionalHeaders=JMS_IBM_Character_Set=UTF-8")

Comment: could you please give any examples for allowAdditionalHeaders property usage with spring boot

Comment: If u set the property true then set the exchange header value to setHeader headerName="JMS_IBM_MQMD_XXXX"

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working fine, in question I mentioned only one-way queue, but if test same for request-reply queue again it's not setting, is there any change for that, could you please inform me

Comment: I changed the question and added both Request queue and Request-Reply queue,your solution is working for Request queue, can you please give solution for Request-Reply queue pattern also , in other file i added JMS_IBM_Character_Set value in exchange object,  exchangeRequest.getIn().setHeader("JMS_IBM_Character_Set", "UTF-8");